# Visual studio adds blank lines when Notepad does not

Tags: c#, visual-studio, format

I'm trying to open a file in an existing project in Notepad, and it is formatted normally:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MyForm : Form
    {
        #region Members

        // etc...
```

But when I open it in Visual Studio it appears different, as though Visual Studio is adding new blank lines between every line:

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.ComponentModel;

using System.Data;

using System.Drawing;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Windows.Forms;



namespace MyNamespace

{

    public partial class MyForm : Form

    {

        #region Members

        // etc...
```

Now one of my co-workers suggested that I check the checkbox under

> Tools->Options->Environment->Documents->Check for consistent line
>   endings on load

but they were not sure what to do afterwards.

The code is very hard to read this way, and I'm afraid I'll mess the code in the repository if I check it in.

This is the case for both Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using git?

Comment: Use regular replace: **(\r?\n){2,}** to **\n**.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. @salitio: we're using Perforce and Swarm for Reviews, not Git.

Comment: @Lei Yang: Thank you for the suggestion. I've tried this Regular Expression Replace, and it removed ALL blank lines, including the legitimate ones...

Answer (score 0):

notpad only knows about **\r\n** while VS supports alot more https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409797.aspx this means that the
file have one of the "line-break" characters that notepad isn't supporting
most likely it's a solo `\n`, try sublime regex replace and investigate what character is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters have implied, it looks like you may be in a scenario where the file is using DOS/Windows-style line endings of a carriage return + line feed (\r\n), but Visual Studio thinks your file is in a UNIX/Linux format where only a line feed is needed, and is showing both.  Notepad, on the other hand, always expects DOS/Windows-style line endings.

If this is the case, try changing this setting and reopening the file:
**Tools => Options => Environments => Documents => Check for consistent line ending on load** in VS2015.

Otherwise, try the regular expression provided above in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I've tried both Windows and UNIX formats when the dialog would pop up, and neither of them made a difference. Further, when I try File->Advanced Save Options and change the Line endings combobox from "Current Setting" to "Windows (CR LF)" and hit OK, if I re-open the dialog the combobox reverts back to "Current Setting."